# grails 2.3. 0 and project tyrus

Tags: spring, tomcat, grails, push-notification, tyrus

Grails 2.3.0 and push notification via [Project Tyrus][1]?

Can grails 2.3.0 play well with Tyrus 1.3?

I have found :http://www.objectpartners.com/2013/06/25/getting-groovy-with-spring-and-websockets/

But this is based on Tyrus 1.0 and this creates some issues with Grizzly.
Latest Tyrus version is 1.3 but I can't figure out how to integrate with the Spring container.
It would be nice to inject some spring services into the ServerEndpoint (https://tyrus.java.net/documentation/1.3.1/user-guide.html#d0e1075)

but even @Inject seems to miss from grails 2.3.0.

Moreover , looks like tyrus is not compatible with tomcat 7 .

Comment: ad Tomcat 7 compatibility: Tyrus requires Servet 3.1 implementation, which is not directly present in Tomcat 7. We have experimental module which provides this, but it is experimental and unsupported: https://github.com/pavelbucek/tyrus/tree/tomcat-experimental

Comment: ad Spring integration - Tyrus does not support that (yet), but you should be able to provide instance from Spring to Tyrus.. via ComponentProvider like it is mentioned in that sample, or via ServerEndpointConfig.Configurator#getEndpointInstance.

Answer (score 1):

Spring beans are declared in the `resources.groovy` file of your application and use a [special DSL format](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/spring.html#springdslAdditional):

```
beans {
  server(Server)
}
```

The dependency injection occurs by name in controllers, services and taglibs (no @Inject needed):

```
class MyController {
  def server

  def index() {
    println server.class.name
  }
}
```

For more information on how Grails use Spring, see the documentation link above.

Comment: Thanks, I am aware of that. The problem is Tyrus is managing his own container , different from the Spring context. How can I involve spring beans in Tyrus cycle ? I need to integrate Spring with Tyrus basically and I can't figure out how to do this in Tyrus 1.3 and grails 2.3.0

Comment: Maybe worth searching for an integration with spring directly, and then translating it to Grails.